# Add image overlay to active class with CSS

Tags: css, image

I'm not sure how to add a semi-transparent color overlay that has centered text in it that says "NOW PLAYING" to a fluid thumbnail image when it is active. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please include a fiddle to demonstrate what you've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering the text vertically won't be so easy, but you can get 95% of the way there with a relatively positioned wrapper div and a CSS pseudo class: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisLTD/FWtA3/

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail active"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.thumbnail.active:after { content: "NOW PLAYING"; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px; text-align: center; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; }
.thumbnail img { display: block; }
```

Comment: vertical centering can be done with two pseudo classes. `top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);` for the text on one and the bg on the other http://jsfiddle.net/FWtA3/3/

Comment: Experimented a little with vertical centered SVG text: http://jsfiddle.net/A9D3X/99/